# Parenthesis content after a specific word

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to get UNIX group names using a regex (can't use `groups` because I can only get the process uid, so I'm using `id <process_id>` to get groups)

input looks like this

```
uid=1001(kawsay) gid=1001(kawsay) groups=1001(kawsay),27(sudo),44(video),997(gpio)\n
```

I'd like to capture `kawsay`, `sudo`, `video` and `gpio`

The only pieces I've got are:

- a positive lookbehind to start capturing after `groups`: `/(?<=groups)/`
- capture the parenthesis content: `/\((\w+)\)/`

Comment: Using Ruby I could do it using `%x(id 1001).scan(/\((\w+)\)/).uniq.map(&:first)` but I'm wondering how to do it using only regex

Comment: What is your intended regex flavor?

Comment: PCRE2 (I'm using Ruby)

Comment: Ruby does not use PCRE2, it uses the Onigmo regex library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```rb
(?:\G(?!\A)\),|\bgroups=)\d+\(\K\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/Eh3UbdwfW3jnA7). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)\),|\bgroups=)` - either of

  - `\G(?!\A)\),` - end of the previous match ([`\G` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) matches either start of string or end of the previous match, so the `(?!\A)` is necessary to exclude the start of string location) and then `),` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `\bgroups=` - a whole word `groups` (`\b` is a word boundary) and then a `=` char
- `\d+\(` - one or more digits and a `(`
- `\K` - match reset operator that makes the regex engine "forget" the text matched so far
- `\w+` - one or more word chars.

Answer (score 4):

Using `PCRE`'s `\G` you may use this regex:

```sh
(?:\bgroups=|(?<!^)\G)[^(]*\(([^)]+)\)
```

Your intended matches are available in capture group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fxXouE/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\bgroups=`: Match word `groups` followed by a `=`
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?<!^)\G`: Start from end position of the previous match
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `[^(]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `(`
- `\(`: Match opening `(`
- `([^)]+)`: Use capture group #1 to match 1+ of any non-`)` characters
- `\)`: Match closing `)`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more ways to extract the strings of interest. Both return matches and do not employ capture groups. My preference is for second one.

```
str = "uid=1001(kawsay) gid=1001(kawsay) groups=1001(kawsay),27(sudo),44(video),997(gpio)\n"
```

---

**Match substrings between parentheses that are not followed later in the string with "groups="**

Match the regular expression

```
rgx = /(?<=\()(?!.*\bgroups=).*?(?=\))/
```

```
str.scan(rgx)
  #=> ["kawsay", "sudo", "video", "gpio"]
```

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/yhOoyEikqCligC)

See [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan).

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=\()      # positive lookbehind asserts previous character is '('
(?!          # begin negative lookahead
  .*         # match zero or more characters
  \bgroups=  # match 'groups=' preceded by a word boundary
)            # end negative lookahead
.*           # match zero or more characters lazily
(?=\))       # positive lookahead asserts next character is ')'
```

This may not be as efficient as expressions that employ `\G` (because of the need to determine if 'groups=' appears in the string after each left parenthesis), but that may not matter.

---

**Extract the portion of the string following `"groups="` and then match substrings between parentheses**

First, obtain the portion of the string that follows `"groups="`:

```
rgx1 = /(?<=\bgroups=).*/
```

```
s = str[rgx1]
  #=> "1001(kawsay),27(sudo),44(video),997(gpio)\n"
```

See [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Then match the regular expression

```
rgx2 = /(?<=\()[^\)\r\n]+/
```

against `s`:

```
s.scan(rgx2)
  #=> ["kawsay", "sudo", "video", "gpio"]
```

The regular expression `rgx1` can be broken down as follows:

```
(?<=\bgroups=) # Positive lookbehind asserts that the current
               # position in the string is preceded by`'groups'`,
               # which is preceded by a word boundary
.*             # match zero of more characters other than line
               # terminators (to end of line)
```

`rgx2` can be broken down as follows:

```
(?<=\()        # Use a positive lookbehind to assert that the
               # following character is preceded by '('
[^\)\r\n]+     # Match one or more characters other than
               # ')', '\r' and '\n'
```

Note:

- The operations can of course be chained: `str[/(?<=\bgroups=).*/].scan(/(?<=\()[^\)\r\n]+/)`; and
- `rgx2` could alternatively be written `/(?<=\().+?(?=\))`, where `?` makes the match of one or more characters lazy and `(?=\))` is a positive lookahead that asserts that the match is followed by a right parenthesis.

This would probably be the fastest solution of those offered and certainly the easiest to test.